I have a date column which have values like this "Jul 28 2023 3:16PM" "2022-09-29 11:30:00" and i want to bring them in one format in sql
"Jul 28 2023  3:16PM"
"Jul 29 2023  3:10PM"
"2022-09-29 11:30:00"
"Nov 20 2022  6:54PM"
"2022-11-26 20:30:00"

Have multiple date formats like this and i want to bring all of them in one standard format without explicitly specifying format
SELECT 
    TRY_CAST(your_date_column AS DATETIME) AS standardized_date
FROM 
    your_table;
But for the "Jul 28 2023  3:16PM" is shows null


You're going to need a separate step for dates formatted like that parsing them appropriately. I hope standardized_date actually is of type datetime

No it's the name of the column that i want to store in

"No it's the name of the column that i want to store in" Yes, and I hope that the type of that column is datetime.

Yes, Can you suggest how can i achieve that?

That will likely depend upon the specific database, which one is it? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, Sqlite, Postgresql, etc. - can you include that in your question?

Yes i have mentioned it in the question

Ah, snowflake - you should probably take a look at the documentation for TO_DATE

Here is a working example of what you could do using Snowflake SQL:
with my_values as (
    select 'Jul 28 2023 3:16PM' as my_date
    union all
    select '2022-09-29 11:30:00'
    union all
    select 'Nov 20 2022 6:54AM'
)

select
    coalesce(
        try_to_timestamp(my_date, 'MON DD YYYY HH12:MIPM'),
        try_to_timestamp(my_date)
    )
from my_values;

Which returns:
2023-07-28 15:16:00.000
2022-09-29 11:30:00.000
2022-11-20 06:54:00.000

